# How to save User object into the Installation for Push notification using Javascript SDK for parse?

Tags: cordova, notifications, push

I guess many folks using this phonegap-parse-plugin plugin will face this issue. Because saving user obj to the installation is needed for targeted push notification. I finally made it work at 4:15am -:) for my ClassMade app (www.iClassMade.com), an app for college students to find girl/boy friends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I figured it after many hours of hacking and search..

I guess many folks using this phonegap-parse-plugin plugin will face this issue. Because saving user obj to the installation is needed for targeted push notification. I finally made it work at 4:15am -:) for my ClassMade app (www.iClassMade.com), an app for college students to find girl/boy friends.

Here is how I made it work. 
I modified the getInstallationId function to let it take one parameter userid

and then in the CDVParsePlugin.m the getInstallationId function
add the following code

```
NSString *userid = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

installation[@"user"] = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User"  objectId:userid];
[installation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
{
if (error != nil)
{
NSLog(@"ParsePushUserAssign save error.");
}
}];
```

then in my html js code, after user login 
just call

```
parsePlugin.getInstallationId(user.id,function(id) {
console.log(id +" id");

                              }, function(e) {
                              console.log('error');
                              });
```

Similarly,  you can add other information to the Installation object, for other targeted push notification using the phonegap platform.